# Проблема с подключением Google Analytics

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать, как подключить google analytics к приложению и где можно взять подробную инструкцию в качестве примера?

Answer (score 1):

Подробную инструкцию и примеры всегда можно найти в [официальной документации](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/?hl=ru)

P.S. Конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Ошибка в шаге добавления отслеживания экранов